# Playframework sbt-native-packager disable subproject packaging

Tags: playframework, sbt-native-packager

I have a Playframework which also has a Play subproject called `auth` since both Plugins have enabled the `PlayScala` Plugin and the `root` project has `.dependsOn(auth).aggregate(auth)` it will always create a `tgz` file for both projects i.e. root-version.tgz and auth-version.tgz, is there a way to disable that behavior for the `auth` project?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply override the task in the `auth` project:

```
packageBin in Universal := {}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: actually that says type mismatch `found: Unit required: java.io.File`

Comment: You can return an empty file then `new File()` for instance. If this throws a "FileNotFoundException", return a temporary file.